# Black 1px line appearing between selected cells of a clear table

Tags: ios, uitableview

Prior to Xcode 5.1 this problem didn't exist for me but now when building my app with 5.1/5.1.1 I'm seeing black horizontal lines appear when my table cells are selected. Both the table view and cells have clear backgrounds and nothing has changed in the code from the time it was working just fine.

[image]

In the `viewDidLoad` method I set the following `tableView` parameters:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
ListViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListViewCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ListViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ListViewCell"];
}

return cell;
```

}

I'm using a `UITableViewCell` subclass which has the following in `awakeFromNib`:

```
UIView *bkgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
bkgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
bkgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.4f];
self.selectedBackgroundView = bkgView;
```

This code worked fine when building in version of Xcode < 5.1 but now I'm seeing different results. Occurs with both Plain and Grouped styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
   [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It shouldn't make a difference since the separator style is set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`